# How to add fields in a specific position in an array in PHP

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and I have a very basic operation to do which is giving me some troubles"

I have an array like this:

```
$array = ['id', 'desc', 'something', 'images', 'test', 'something2', 'something3'];
```

I need to check if there is the value images, if there is replace it with 'image1' and next to it add other fields like these: 'image2', 'image3', 'image4' and so on until 10.

the resulting array would be this.

```
$array = ['id', 'desc', 'something', 'image1', 'image2', 'image3', 'image4', 'image5', 'image6', 'image7', 'image8', 'image9', 'image10', 'test', 'something2', 'something3'];
```

I tried doing this (but I am stuck):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($key === 'images') {
        //'can I use array_slice here?'
    }
}
```

Comment: use `array_splice`, then you only need one line and no loop :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a loop that is suitable for associative arrays.
Here is an example of a loop cyclying through an associative array:

Source: [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_associative.asp)

```
<?php
$age = array("Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"43");

foreach($age as $x => $x_value) {
  echo "Key=" . $x . ", Value=" . $x_value;
  echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Try to use this type of foreach loop instead:

```
foreach( $array as $value ) {
    echo "Value is $value <br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```php
<?php

$images = [];
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) { 
    $images[] = 'image' . $i;
}

$array = ['id', 'desc', 'something', 'images', 'test', 'something2', 'something3'];
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
     if ($value === 'images') {    
        array_splice($array, $key, 1, $images);
        break; 
    }
}

var_dump($array);
```